# this while loop wont give me back the same as the for loop

Tags: java

Could anyone help me why this for loop wont do the same thing as this while loop?

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        int Bits = 0;
        int dataLength = 8;

        System.out.println(dataLength);

        /*
        for(int i = (int) (Math.pow(2,numCheckBits) -1); i < dataLength + Bits; i++){
            numCheckBits = i;
        }
        */

        while ((Math.pow(2, Bits) - 1) < dataLength + Bits)
            Bits++;

        System.out.println(Bits);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = (int) (Math.pow(2,numCheckBits) -1); i < dataLength + Bits; i++){
    numCheckBits = i;
```

When the loop starts, `i` is set to 2<sup>`numCheckBits`</sup>-1.  Then, each time through the loop, it is increased by 1.  Thus, if `numCheckBits` starts out as 0, `i` will take on the values 1, 2, 3, ..., `dataLength + Bits - 1`.  Reassigning `numCheckBits` inside the loop has **no** effect on this, because the expression using `numCheckBits` is computed only at the beginning of the loop.

```
while ((Math.pow(2, Bits) - 1) < dataLength + Bits)
    Bits++;
```

In this case, the expression involving `Math.pow` is evaluated each time.  This means that `Bits` takes on the values 0, 1, ... floor(log<sub>2</sub>`(dataLength + Bits)`) or something like that.

The `for` loop that would be equivalent to your `while` loop would have `Math.pow` as the **second** expression, so that that value will be tested against `dataLength + Bits` each time:

```
for (int i = 0; Math.pow(2,i)-1 < dataLength + i; i++) {
}
```

[or whatever you want to do inside the loop--you may not need `numCheckBits` any more].

Comment: how would i go about making this for loop to do what the while is

Comment: haha o ok. but in the While loop the Bits++ is important to me because at the end the value ends up to be int value of 4, so does your for loop provide me with the same int value

Comment: I made a mistake, which I fixed.  The last value of `i` will be the value you want.  The way I wrote it, you can't get at it because of the scope, but you can put `int i;` before the `for` loop, and start with `for (i = 0 ...` instead of `for (int i = 0` ... and now you can access `i` after the loop is done.  You can change the name of `i` to `Bits` of you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

The exact translation of your `for` loop

```
for(int i = (int) (Math.pow(2,numCheckBits) -1); i < dataLength + Bits; i++){
    numCheckBits = i;
}
```

to a `while` loop is:

```
int i= (int) (Math.pow(2, numCheckBits) -1);
while (i < dataLength + Bits)
{
    numCheckBits = i;
    i++;
}
```